# remove subsection bar in Darmstadt theme, beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, navigation

I am using the Darmstadt theme in beamer and would like to remove the subsection titles in the navigation bar. Is there any easy way to do this without changing the color scheme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `\usetheme{Frankfurt}` instead of `\usetheme{Darmstadt}`.

The reason is that `beamerthemedarmstadt.sty` is defined as follows:

```
\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\mode
<all>
```

`beamerthemefrankfurt.sty` has the same definition, with one small difference:

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
```

which hides the subsection in the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off the subsection bar with `\beamer@sb@subsectionfalse`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\makeatletter
\beamer@sb@subsectionfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]